# How to get the progress at a given point in time from CAMediaTimingFunction?

Tags: ios, swift

There is a `CAMediaTimingFunction`. (This is the easing of `easeInQuart`.)

```
let timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22)
```

I want to pass a time in the range `[0, 1]` to this `timingFunction` to get an output in the range `[0, 1]`.
For example, if I pass `0.5`, it should output a value smaller than 0.5 because it is `easeInQuart` (slow at first).

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Not magically, but you can certainly do the calculation yourself. See https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/